# global event catch for QEventfilter class

Tags: qt, events, qevent

I want to add a help webpage for my Qt Application. The user can use the Qt::WhatsThis "tooltip" to have a explanation about the topic and a URL to a webpage. I edit the WhatsthisTooltips with the Qt Designer and have it language indepentend.

Now I create a "LinkFilter" class for filtering, install it in the viewclass and react on the QEvent::WhatsThisClicked event. This works fine.

Now i would catch every QEvent::WhatsThisClicked in my application, but i looks really messy to install it on really every dialog/view/action/widget. This there some kind of global eventHandler, were I can install my "LinkEvent"class? There must be a nice Qt style way for solving this.

For installing the EventFilter I strongly followed this video-tutorial http://youtu.be/DHgbYxpZkbg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#notify

Essentially you need to subclass `QApplication` and override this function. Then you can check if it's the type of event you're looking for and act accordingly.

Comment: The hint with the QApplication class was very good. I could easly install the event at the application class. Now it catches every singal without changing the "normal" behavior.   QApplication qApplication(argc, argv);
  LinkFilter* filter = new LinkFilter(this);
  qApplication.installEventFilter(filter);